# Set a value of ilist<T> members

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }      
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public IList<ProductFiles> ProductFiles { get; set; }                     
}

public class ProductFiles
{
    public int NumberOfFiles { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfShops { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am trying to set the value of the property `NumberOfFiles` (member of `ProductFiles`):

```
public Products CountProductFiles(int productId)
{    
    DB_utilities db = new DB_utilities();
    object[] spParams = new object[] { productId};

    Products product = new Products();

    using (var reader = db.procSelect("[Products_CountFiles]", spParams))
    {
        reader.Read();
        {
            Products _products = new Products 
            {                        
                ProductName = (string)reader["ProductName"],
                Price = (double)reader["Price"],

                // I am trying to do something like this but this does not work:
                ProductFiles.NumberOfFiles = (int)reader["NumberOfFiles"]  
            };

            Products = _products ;
        }
    }

    return Products;
}
```

How can I set the value of the prop `NumberOfFiles`? Or is the entire concept wrong?

Comment: It looks like you wanted to make `NumberOfFiles` property `static`?

Comment: Your class names should not be plural.

Comment: I want to be able to set the value of 'NuberOfFiles', do I need to set it as 'static'?

Comment: you dont need another class for keeping track of the number of instances of one class. Declare 2 static int and in the constructor of your class increment these counters and in the distrucotr decrement the counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `ProductFiles` is a collection of `ProductFiles`, you need to do this

```
Products p = new Products();
p.ProductFiles = new List<ProductFiles>();
p.ProductFiles.Add(new ProductFiles() { NumberOfFiles  = 1 }); // or some other defined value.
```

The collection needs to be initialized before adding objects to it.
In your example, you do not treat `ProductFiles` as a collection, that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a collection is that it can contain zero or more items.  You need to put an instance in the collection.  You also need to create a collection to ensure that the collection itself is not null.

```
new Product { 
    Files = new List<ProductFile>() { 
        new ProductFile {
            FileCount = 42
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, Products::ProductFiles is a list.
Hence, in order to set the value of NumberOfFiles, do something like this:

```
ProductFiles[i].NumberOfFiles = //whatever you want to set it to.
```

But, before doing all this, do not forget to instantiate the List variable. Otherwise, it will itself be NULL.